# Smoke collision with emitter object

Tags: smoke-simulation

How do I make an the emitter object of smoke collide with the smoke/fire itself?

For example, I want to simulate the plasmaflow of a capsule reentering the atmosphere. How do I get the fire to curve around the capsule and not go through it?

Here the capsule is hollow on the inside but has thickness. Only the bottom faces emit fire and there is a wind force applied from the bottom. On the left picture there is still fire on the inside of the capsule. 
[image: Capsule]